# Cannot use `time` keyword in Makefile rule action

Tags: linux, bash, make

I have a simple Makefile:

```
run : 
	time echo foo
```

Here's the output when I use it:

```
$ make run
time echo foo
make: time: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:2: run] Error 127
```

Why doesn't it work? As I understand, `time` is keyword in `bash` (unless you also installed the `time` *program*, which I haven't), and `Makefile` uses `sh` as the default shell, but I have that simlinked to `bash`. Here's some other relevant output:

```
$ type -a time
time is a shell keyword
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ ls -l "$(which sh)"
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Apr 30 05:13 /usr/bin/sh -> bash
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
$ ls -l /bin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 May 23 10:18 /bin -> usr/bin
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Apr 30 05:13 /bin/sh -> bash
$ /bin/sh -c 'time true'

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

edit: note also that `/bin` is simlinked to `/usr/bin`, so the issue is not due to a distinction between /bin/sh and /usr/bin/sh. Also I'm using  Arch Linux, with latest `pacman -Syu` update as of today June 28, 2019.

Also, here is the result of a hexdump of the Makefile:

```
$ xxd Makefile
00000000: 7275 6e20 3a0a 0974 696d 6520 6563 686f  run :..time echo
00000010: 2066 6f6f 0a                              foo.
```

Comment: What is the output of `/bin/sh -c 'time true'`?

Comment: just added that toward the end of the post.

Comment: the output for `make` in that case is `lrwxrwxrwx 1 xdavidliu xdavidliu 0 Jun 30 09:12 /proc/2476/exe -> /usr/bin/ls`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one trick shells do. Try `ls -l /proc/$$$$/exe; true` in the makefile.

Comment: okay, the output when I add `; true` is `lrwxrwxrwx 1 xdavidliu xdavidliu 0 Jun 30 16:31 /proc/11816/exe -> /usr/bin/bash`

Comment: A non-printable character hiding in `time` may manifest itself like this. It's a long shot but let's explicitly rule this possibility out (e.g. examine the output of `xxd Makefile`).

Comment: I added the `xxd` output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having `sh` symlinked to `bash` does not mean that invoking `sh` will be equivalent to invoking `bash`.

This is what [Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Command-line_shell) says:

```
When Bash, mksh and zsh are invoked with the sh name, 
they automatically become more POSIX compliant.
```

That means that some features will not be available and you should still choose `bash` as a shell in your `Makefile` if you need the features of `bash`.

Add this as the first line of your `Makefile` to choose `bash` as a shell:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

This should solve your issue.

More about choosing the shell can be found in [the GNU Make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell)

Comment: simlinking `sh` to `bash` is the default used by archlinux

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. However, according to archwiki the behavior is still different even when symlinked: "When Bash, mksh and zsh are invoked with the sh name, they automatically become more POSIX compliant." https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Command-line_shell

Comment: I'm editing my answer to include that.